# quicksort Iterative + animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, quicksort

I wanted to create a quicksort  iterative sorting algorithm that will show me the progress of an animation. I use matplotlib.animation for this purpose. The problem arises when after passing the first sort and setting new pivot points, the program stops working showing an error:

> for rect, val in zip(rects, A):
> TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

Code with a sorting function:

```
def partition(a, l, r):
    i = (l - 1)
    x = a[r]

    for j in range(l, r):
        if a[j] <= x:
            # increment index of smaller element
            i = i + 1
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]

    a[i + 1], a[r] = a[r], a[i + 1]
    return (i + 1)


def quickSortIterative(a, l, r):
    # Create an auxiliary stack
    size = r - l + 1
    stack = [0] * (size)

    # initialize top of stack
    top = -1

    # push initial values of l and h to stack
    top = top + 1
    stack[top] = l
    top = top + 1
    stack[top] = r

    # Keep popping from stack while is not empty
    while top >= 0:

        # Pop h and l
        r = stack[top]
        top = top - 1
        l = stack[top]
        top = top - 1

        # Set pivot element at its correct position in
        # sorted array
        if l >= r:
            return
        x = a[l]
        j = l
        for i in range(l + 1, r + 1):
            if a[i] <= x:
                j += 1
                a[j], a[i] = a[i], a[j]
            yield a
        a[l], a[j] = a[j], a[l]
        yield a
        # If there are elements on left side of pivot,
        # then push left side to stack
        for i in a:
            if i - 1 > l:
                top = top + 1
                stack[top] = l
                top = top + 1
                stack[top] = i - 1
                yield stack[top]

            # If there are elements on right side of pivot,
            # then push right side to stack

            if i + 1 < r:
                top = top + 1
                stack[top] = i + 1
                top = top + 1
                stack[top] = r
                yield stack[top]
```

Drawing a graph:

```
def draw2(n=None):
    n = int(n)
    a = [x + 1 for x in range(n)]
    random.shuffle(a)
    datasetName = 'Random'

    # generator object returned by the function
    generator = quickSortIterative(a, 0, n - 1)
    algoName = 'Quick Sort2'

    # style of the chart
    plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # bar container
    bar_rects = ax.bar(range(len(a)), a, align="edge",
                       color='Blue')

    # setting the limits of x and y axes
    ax.set_xlim(0, len(a))
    ax.set_ylim(0, int(1.1 * len(a)))
    ax.set_title("ALGORITHM : " + algoName + "\n" + "DATA SET : " +
                 datasetName)

    text = ax.text(0.01, 0.95, "", transform=ax.transAxes, color="#E4365D")
    iteration2 = [0]

    def animate(A, rects, iteration2):
        for rect, val in zip(rects, A):
            # setting the size of each bar equal to the value of the elements
            rect.set_height(val)
        iteration2[0] += 1
        text.set_text("iterations : {}".format(iteration2[0]))

    # call animate function repeatedly
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animate,
                         fargs=(bar_rects, iteration2), frames=generator, interval=50,
                         repeat=False)
    plt.show()
```

How can I fix the error so that the program sorts all the elements?

Comment: `bar_rects` is not iterable. Unfortunately, you didn't post a working minimal example, so I can't check which type is `bar_rects`.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75076584/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what I can minimize. I assume that the error is in the file with sorting, but the file where the graph is drawn generates an error for me, cutting out a fragment will make it unreadable for locating the problem